# How to make a Hebrew-English keyboard layout combo behave like in Windows?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout, hebrew

I would like my he-IL/en-US Keyboard layoutas in Lubuntu 15.04 to behave like it does in MS Windows, with respect to Hebrew. That probably means a lot of things, not all of which I'm aware of, but at the very least:

- Same behavior in virtual terminals and in X sessions
- Ctrl+Shift switches direction  <-- (yes I know this one is hard and maybe out-of-scope. I still need it to work.)
- Alt+Shift switches keyboard layout
- Caps Lock in Hebrew layout gives me capital English letters instead of Hebrew letters - but I still get the non-letter characters of the Hebrew layout! i.e. it doesn't act like a layout switch.
- Applications accept Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V and other similar English-letter shortcuts also when I'm in Hebrew layout.
- Win+Space doesn't switch layouts (actually I don't really mind all that much)
- In Hebrew layout, punctuation is available with Caps Lock and Shift + number keys.
- No using the Scroll Lock indicator led for indication which layout is in effect!